# Backend for embedded matplotlib in cocoa

Tags: python, objective-c, macos, cocoa, matplotlib

Sorry for the novice question but I was wondering if anyone knows about embedding matplotlib plotting functions into a cocoa app?  I have been able to open a plot within the app using the cocoa backend but every time I close the plot window the entire app closes (I assume its stopping the run loop).  I have done some investigating a realise that the cocoa backend was originally designed for implementation into apps but it appears it is still taking over the run loop.  I would like to avoid using bitmaps and NSImage if possible as this removes the interaction capabilities of matplotlib, which are very useful to me.

Many thanks!